# Can I visit Israel if I have 2 passports, one of them is Lebanese but will apply for visa with the other one?

Tags: tourist-visas, dual-nationality, israel, lebanese-citizens, armenian-citizens

Suppose a person is born in Armenia (and has an Armenian passport).  Ones first nationality is Armenian, but then acquired the Lebanese passport due to the father being born in Lebanon and having the nationality. However, neither the father nor the person *have ever lived in Lebanon*. They have been living in Jordan with a residency permit.

If the person wants to apply to visa to visit Jerusalem (to celebrate the Armenian Christmas with relatives and friends in January) with the *Armenian* passport, and provided the Jordanian residency permit that says nationality is *Lebanese*. **Will they be able to get the visa**? Or it will be rejected knowing all of the above?

Comment: Related: [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel). Why would you have to submit the Jordanian residency permit?

Answer (score 3):

Israel does *not* have a policy against [issuance of visas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Israel) to Lebanese. Such visas require confirmation from the Israeli Government, unlike an Armenian passport, which can be done at the Embassy level. I have no idea if the "Lebanese" entry on your Jordanian residence permit, which the Embassy probably see when they ask why you are applying from Jordan and not Armenia, will require the referral back to Jerusalem. Even if it does, however, there is no reason to think that your application will be rejected.

Not only does Lebanon have a policy not to issue a visa in an Israeli passport, I believe it is also a *crime* to visit Israel on a Lebanese passport. You should investigate whether your visit would leave you liable to arrest in Lebanon, should you ever go there, even if you visited on your Armenian passport.

EDIT: Probably worth adding, so as not to make Lebanon look unusual, that holders of *Israeli* passports may be prosecuted for visiting Lebanon without a special permit, independent of whether the Lebanese would admit them (for example, if they entered Lebanon using another passport based on dual citizenship).

Comment: It's not a crime to visit Israel on a Lebanese passport, if you have a visa. Getting it is simply hard, as Lebanon is an enemy state.

Comment: @ugoren Not a crime in _Israel_, but in Lebanon, at least not without special permission. Didn't a Lebanese Christian cleric get in trouble for this?